# How can I draw a BufferedImage onto the screen using LWJGL?

Tags: java, image, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I want to know how to draw textures with BufferedImages in LWJGL Java.
Does anyone know how to do this or is it impossible?

Comment: What error does you get?

Comment: I don't get errors, I just don't have a clue how to draw BufferedImages onto the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw an image onto the screen, you first need to get the [Graphics object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html), of the Container or Component you're painting it onto. Then using that Graphics Object, call the [drawImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) method, and supply the relevant details. This will output the image into the container, in the position that you decide.

Comment: Could I not do it using OpenGL like;

texture.bind();
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);

Comment: After a 30 second google, I came up with [this link](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25516.0).

Comment: Thank you!
Woah, sorry Chris, I must have been Googling wrong! xD